# Array not resetting after second time through

Tags: javascript

I have written code where the user moves through a switch statement by hitting the enter button on the keyboard until the end of the array is reached. Then a modal appears asking the user to click on a button if they wish to repeat the exercise. After clicking the button the code works fine the first time through, but any subsequent attempt shows the code being locked-up within an else if statement without going on to showing the modal as it had done at first. I have tried relentlessly to get this to go but I am at a total loss. Suggestions?

I had gotten the code to run and reset properly, but at the cost of the modal remaining open on the screen. Not desirable/acceptable.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/don199/pen/qBXXYdL?editors=1111

```
    <div>Click in the blue area to gain focus, then hit the enter button on the keyboard to advance through the array.</div>
<div class="displayColor"></div>
<div class="modal-overlay"></div>
<button class='button'>yes</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
    
<script>
let colors = [0, 1, 2, 3];
let displayColor = document.querySelector('.displayColor');

function init(){
    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    num = colors[randNum];
    colors.splice(randNum, 1); 

    switch(num){
    case 0:
        displayColor.textContent = 'blue';
        break; 
    case 1: 
        displayColor.textContent = 'green';
        break;
    case 2:
        displayColor.textContent = 'yellow';
        break;
    case 3:
        displayColor.textContent = 'orange';
        break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && colors.length > 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        init();
    } else if(e.keyCode == 13 && colors.length < 1) {
        gsap.to(displayColor, 0,{autoAlpha: 0});
        showModal();
        
        console.log('empty array');
    }
})

let btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let tl_showModal = gsap.timeline();
    tl_showModal
        .reversed(true)
        
        .to(displayColor, 0,{autoAlpha: 0})
        .to('.modal-overlay', {duration: .5, autoAlpha: 1}, 0)
        .to(document.querySelector('.displayColor'), {autoAlpha: 1,textContent: 'Wanna go again?'})
        .to(btn,{autoAlpha: 1})
            
function showModal(){
    tl_showModal.play(); 

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(colors.length === 0){
            gsap.to(btn,{autoAlpha: 0});
            gsap.to('.modal-overlay', {duration: .5, autoAlpha: 0});
            colors = [0,1,2,3];
            init();
       }       
    }) 
}   

init();
```

Comment: I do not fully understand the expected behaviour of your code, but are you sure you want to add an eventListener each time to your `btn` as you call `showModal()`?

Comment: I would think normally not, Habebit, but as the final product worked-out, it adds a nice touch by prompting the user to click a button.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the array is actually resetting, the problem has to do with setup of tl_showModal only happening once on initialization. What fixes the problem is to move the tl_showModal setup into the init function. So you code would look something like this

```
<div>Click in the blue area to gain focus, then hit the enter button on the 
keyboard to advance through the array.</div>
<div class="displayColor"></div>
<div class="modal-overlay"></div>
<button class='button'>yes</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.6.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
    
<script>
let colors = [0, 1, 2, 3];
let displayColor = document.querySelector('.displayColor');
let btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let tl_showModal = gsap.timeline();

function init(){
    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    num = colors[randNum];
    colors.splice(randNum, 1); 

    tl_showModal
        .reversed(true)
        
        .to(displayColor, 0,{autoAlpha: 0})
        .to('.modal-overlay', {duration: .5, autoAlpha: 1}, 0)
        .to(document.querySelector('.displayColor'), {autoAlpha: 1,textContent: 'Wanna go again?'})
        .to(btn,{autoAlpha: 1})

    switch(num){
    case 0:
        displayColor.textContent = 'blue';
        break; 
    case 1: 
        displayColor.textContent = 'green';
        break;
    case 2:
        displayColor.textContent = 'yellow';
        break;
    case 3:
        displayColor.textContent = 'orange';
        break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && colors.length > 0){
        e.preventDefault();
        init();
    } else if(e.keyCode == 13 && colors.length < 1) {
        gsap.to(displayColor, 0,{autoAlpha: 0});
        showModal();
        
        console.log('empty array');
    }
})
            
function showModal(){
    tl_showModal.play(); 

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(colors.length === 0){
            gsap.to(btn,{autoAlpha: 0});
            gsap.to('.modal-overlay', {duration: .5, autoAlpha: 0});
            colors = [0,1,2,3];
            init();
       }       
    }) 
}   

init();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the code provided isn't working when placed in the Codepen. But it gives me a different approach to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be the approach I used on the modal. I used a timeline to open it, but then made it disappear to 'close' it, rather than reversing the timeline (simply reversing the timeline, however, added a whole other world of headache). By eliminating the timeline and placing all the code in showModal(), it worked as desired.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/don199/pen/MWvVMbG

```
function showModal(){
gsap.to(displayColor, 0,{autoAlpha: 0});
gsap.to('.modal-overlay', {duration: .5, autoAlpha: 1});
gsap.to(document.querySelector('.displayColor'), {autoAlpha: 1,textContent: 'Wanna go again?'});
gsap.to(btn,{autoAlpha: 1});

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(colors.length === 0){
        gsap.to(btn,{autoAlpha: 0});
        gsap.to('.modal-overlay', {duration: .5, autoAlpha: 0});
        colors = [0,1,2,3];
        init();
    }       
})
```

}